# Error in generating javadoc using UMLGraph, getting error in processing "dot file"

Tags: java, ant, uml, umlgraph

I am trying to generate class diagram from the source code through UmlGraph.
I have built and created the umlgraph.jar but while i am using it in my project it is giving me the below error ::

```
[javadoc] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dot": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:466)
  [javadoc]     at org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc.runGraphviz(UmlGraphDoc.java:131)
  [javadoc]     at org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc.generatePackageDiagrams(UmlGraphDoc.java:95)
  [javadoc]     at org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc.start(UmlGraphDoc.java:63)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [javadoc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  [javadoc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
  [javadoc]     at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

I have downloaded the GraphViz and set the path for the graphviz. 
please help me guys i am new to this one.

The javadoc target in ant file ::

```
    <fileset dir="${srcroot.dir}" >
            <filename name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>

               <doclet name="org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc"
                  path="${umlLib.dir}/UmlGraph.jar">
                    <param name="-attributes"  />
                    <param name="-operations"  />
                    <param name="-qualify" />
                    <param name="-types"  />
                    <param name="-visibility"  />
                </doclet>
              </javadoc>
      <apply executable="dot" dest="${reports.dir}" parallel="false">
        <arg value="-Tpng"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
         <targetfile/>
         <srcfile/>
         <fileset dir="${reports.dir}" includes="*.dot"/>
         <mapper type="glob" from="*.dot" to="*.png"/>
      </apply>
</target>
```

Comment: Ant isn't finding "dot" or "dot.exe" on the PATH. What OS are you running (Windows, Unix, etc.)?

Comment: @ChadNouis :: i am using windows 7

Comment: @ChadNouis :: i have downloaded the graphViz dot file processor from http://www.graphviz.org/Download_source.php, and gave the path of the bin..actually i m trying to do this by following this tutorial::http://java.dzone.com/articles/reverse-engineer-source-code-u

Comment: In a Command Prompt, run the following and post the output: `ant -diagnostics | findstr java.library.path`

Comment: Where's you dot executable located? Does the path contain whitespace like `program files`?

Comment: @coolcfan :: it is not containning the program files.

Comment: @ChadNouis :: actually now the error coming is ::
dot.exe has stopped working.. now actually the dot file is executing.
it is working sometime but in most of the cases it is not.
sorry for the delay in answering.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same "dot" message.  http://sourceforge.net/p/schemaspy/discussion/462849/thread/38a9bfad/#7a89 indicates to restart your machine after installing GraphViz and adding it to your path.  I did this and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add path to \graphviz-2.38\release to your classpath and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the common issues about the mysql-connector and the dot executable file. It's not necessary to restart the machine if you pass the correct value to -gv, believe me. I've installed the Graphviz and found the mysql-connector performing a sorted search of *.jar files.

The following lines are how I executed the statement.

```
java 
-jar schemaSpy.jar 
-t mysql 
-o library 
-host localhost 
-db dummyDB 
-u user
-p user
-dp C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oracle_common\modules\mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.22\mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.22-bin.jar 
-gv "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38"
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires installation of GraphViz. Information is available here. https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/